# Unable to access users calendar using application daemon token

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, access-token, azure-ad-msal, outlook-restapi, http-status-code-401

I have been trying to access a user's data using the MS graph API. I have been following the official documentation and I have correctly configured the apps and the permission.

I am also following this [code_sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-daemon/tree/master/msal-client-credential-secret) and using this I have been able to fetch the daemon token for the application.

Using the token I am able to successfully fetch the data against the following endpoint:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/204e3e4f-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-509934e1
```

The data looks like:

```
{"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users/$entity","businessPhones":[],"displayName":"developers@outlook.com Tiwari","givenName":"developers@outlook.com","jobTitle":null,"mail":null,"mobilePhone":null,"officeLocation":null,"preferredLanguage":null,"surname":"Tiwari","userPrincipalName":"developers_outlook.com#EXT#@webdevelopers.onmicrosoft.com","id":"204e3e4f-x-xxxxx-xxxxxxx-509934e14fa8"}
```

However, I can't fetch any more data than this. All the other endpoints throw a 401 Unauthorised exception even when I have checked all the Application permission for my app.

I am trying to hit the following endpoints for fetching calendar of the above user:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/204e3e4f-xxxx-xx-xxxxz-509934e14fa8/calendar
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/204e3e4f-xxx-xxx-xxxxx-509934e14fa8/calendars
```

both of these give 401.

Can someone suggest if I am missing something. I even decompiled my jwt token and it clearly shows all the following scopes added:

```
"roles": [
    "Schedule.ReadWrite.All",
    "OnlineMeetings.Read.All",
    "Mail.ReadWrite",
    "OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All",
    "User.ReadWrite.All",
    "Calendars.Read",
    "Mail.ReadBasic.All",
    "Files.ReadWrite.All",
    "User.Read.All",
    "Schedule.Read.All",
    "Files.Read.All",
    "Organization.ReadWrite.All",
    "Mail.Read",
    "Calendars.ReadWrite",
    "Mail.Send",
    "Organization.Read.All",
    "Mail.ReadBasic"
  ],
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

To get access to calendar events you should call the following endpoint:

```
GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/events
```

The documentations for calendars is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-events

Comment: I have tried the above API as well and it gives the same 401 response. I do not think its an endpoint error. Somehow it appears that the token is not getting authorised for the calendar access. Although I have no clue why it would be so ?

Comment: @saurabhTiwari what type of account are you using? A personal account (Microsoft Account) or a work account (AAD/Org ID)?

Comment: I am using a personal microsoft (outlook) account.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment on Chris Johnson's answer, you're using a personal account. App-only tokens won't work to access a personal account, and you shouldn't be able to even obtain one using a personal account, since there's no concept of an admin.

App-only requires an admin to consent, and when she does, she grants access to all resources in her tenant. Personal accounts are not in work/school tenants, so they aren't in scope. Even if you've added that personal account as a guest in the work/school tenant, their calendar is hosted outside of the tenant, and is off limits.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but what if the person from the work/school tenant has shared their calendar with my personal account. Any ways to make it work then ?